# Coudln't fix the image overflow while hover?

Tags: html, css

```css
.gallery-wrapper
    img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.masnory-image {
    position: relative;

}

.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0.7
    );
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity
        0.4s;
    }
.image-overlay
    .gallery-wrapper{
    transform: translateY(
        20px
    );
    transition: transform
        0.4s;
}
.image-overlay:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.image-overlay:hover
    .gallery-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(
        0
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
      <div class="masnory-image">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="">
          <div class="image-overlay">
            <h3>Portfolio</h3>
            <p>Ethan Hunt</p>
          </div>
        </a>  
      </div>
 </div>
```

When I hover on this image some extra layer has been appearing. I tried a lot giving overflow hidden. but it didn't work for me. I don't get understand about it properly that how it works. please help me to get out of this problem.

To more clearance, I snippet my code here. It will be more easy for you to understand what I try to saying.

Answer (score 0):

hi there your question is not clear Can you Please tell me what do you want to do
As according to you
there is an overlay as it has been set by your side

```
.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0.7
    );
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity
        0.4s;
    }
```

can you please give a more breif instructions

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is when i hover on my image then some overflow is seen in the bottom which is basically show after setting margin bottom:20px. But, I need those margin without overflow. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi brother acutally you have given margin-bottom: 20px there you need to remove that

Answer (score 0):

You have given `margin-bottom` to the image, that's why it was taking some space at the bottom. I have modified your snippet.

```
.gallery-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0; // Make this 0px
    vertical-align: top; // add this property also to adjust a slight spacing
}
```

Have a look.

Thanks me later.

**Update:** Give margin in the `gallery-wrapper` not in the `img`. Like this.

```
.gallery-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I have Updated my Code. Have a look.

```css
.gallery-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.gallery-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.masnory-image {
    position: relative;
}
.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0.7
    );
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity
        0.4s;
    }
.image-overlay
    .gallery-wrapper{
    transform: translateY(
        20px
    );
    transition: transform
        0.4s;
}
.image-overlay:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.image-overlay:hover
    .gallery-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(
        0
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
      <div class="masnory-image">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="">
          <div class="image-overlay">
            <h3>Portfolio</h3>
            <p>Ethan Hunt</p>
          </div>
        </a>  
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: But, I need that margint-bottom:20px .How can I do that? because when I don't set margin bottom, there will not remains any gap between two divs vertically. And If i give margin bottom, then overflow appears.

Comment: You have given margin-bottom in .gallery-wrapper img. Give margin in only gallery-wrapper. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: finally, i did it. wrongly i give margin-bottom in .gallery-wrapper img but when i set margin-bottom in .gallery-wrappe it works perfect as i want. thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Now since you want to keep your `margin-bottom:20px`, then the only way to solve your issue is to reduce the height of the overlay from `height:100%` since this will create the overflow of the `20px` to `height:99%`. 
But even that wont work well on smaller screen sizes, so you have to **add media queries** so that the overlay adapts well to all screen sizes.

**N/B: I dont know why you need the margin-bottom of 20px and I still think you can achieve the same without it.**
That said, this is my solution with the media queries altering the height of your overlay, you can play around with those decimals to achieve perfection.

```css
.gallery-wrapper
    img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.masnory-image {
    position: relative;

}

.image-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
.image-overlay
    .gallery-wrapper{
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.image-overlay:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.image-overlay:hover
    .gallery-wrapper {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .image-overlay{height:99%}
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .image-overlay{height:99%}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .image-overlay{height:99%}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .image-overlay{height:98.4%}
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .image-overlay{height:97.6%}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .image-overlay{height:97%}
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
      <div class="masnory-image">
        <a href="">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" alt="">
          <div class="image-overlay">
            <h3>Portfolio</h3>
            <p>Ethan Hunt</p>
          </div>
        </a>  
      </div>
 </div>
```